# OnClickListener for CustomView in RelyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I need to set `OnClickListener` for `CutomView` (Button), which is in `RelyclerView`. The problem is that I can catch click on `View`, but not for `CustomView`. Any ideas?

I catch click in this way:

My CustomAdapter:

```
...
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv, parent, false);

        view.setOnClickListener(TestActivity.myOnClickListener);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }
...
```

And in MainActivity:

```
...
private static class MyOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

        private final Context context;

        private MyOnClickListener(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_map_1: {
            }
                Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // And nothing happens
            }
        }
        }
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From whatever code you have posted, it seems you are not setting the `onClickListener` to the correct view. In your code,

```
view.setOnClickListener(TestActivity.myOnClickListener);
```

You are setting the `onClickListener` to the view, whereas you want to set it to the Custom View (Button). So suppose in your `rv.xml` file, your custom view (button) is defined with id as `button_map_1`, then your code should be

```
view.findViewById(R.id.button_map_1).setOnClickListener(TestActivity.myOnClickListener);
```

This would set the `onClickListener` on the button `button_map_1`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend inside your adapter you create a listener to catch your views clicks. Then the activity can attach to on the adapter with setChildClickListener.

Like this:

```
class MyAdapter
{
    View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener;

    public void setChildClickListener(View.OnClickListener l)
    {
        mOnClickListener = l;
    }

    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv, parent, false);

        view.setOnClickListener(mClicks);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    View.OnClickListener mClicks = new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (null != mOnClickListener) {
                mOnClickListener.onClick(v);
            }
        }
    };
}
```